# Undefined method when trying to upload profile image

Tags: laravel, image, profile

So I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-upload-profile-image-of-users-in-laravel/) tutorial to make my users been able to upload a profile picture.

But in the HomeController is giving me "undifined method" in the final "update".

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Flight;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $filename = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->image->storeAs('images',$filename,'public');
            Auth()->user()->update(['image'=>$filename]);
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

I already tried to 'use' Eloquent above, thinking it was the update method from it, but it still doesn't work.

Is there something that i need to call first for it to work?

[error printScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVANm.png)

Comment: try $user = User::find(auth()->id());
 
 $user->update(['image'=>$filename]);
 
 or 
 
  $user = User::find(auth()->id());
 
 $user->image=$filename;
 $user->save();

Comment: Ok, now it doesn't give the error on the update but gives on the user:: Undefined type 'App\Http\Controllers\User'.

Comment: you have to import user model like use App\Models\User;

Answer (score 2):

auth()->user() return a auth facade instanc but
when you need to update data you need a Model instance so

```
$userData = user::find(auth()->user()->id);
$userData->image = $filename;
$userData.save()
```

Comment: Auth facades instance only use for retrieving data on login user form session

Comment: Ok, now it doesn't give the error on the update but gives on the user::

Undefined type 'App\Http\Controllers\User'.

Comment: You need to import User model at the top for controller
Use App/model/User
Sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

Add this in  routes/web.php  file...

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Comment: Just did
Still gives the same error :(

Comment: can you comment the error message?

Comment: it doesn't give an error using it.
It says 'Undefined method 'update'' in visual code like i did show up in the 'error printScreen'

Answer (score 0):

as user @raghav said, using Auth->user() gives you an auth user instance,
instead you want to find a user from the collection by using the Auth id, ex :

```
$userData = User::find(auth()->id);
$userData->image = $filename;
$userData->save();
```

Comment: Ok, now it doesn't give the error on the update but gives on the user::

Undefined type 'App\Http\Controllers\User'.